# Why is my div overlapping other divs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so on mobile screen size when in landscape the other divs do not overlap.
I cant get the div's to stay at certain space away from each other.
here is my code :

```css
/* Main Section */

html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: -100;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('https://i.gyazo.com/fbb65627e5fe8a07b7d4b9d41db47e34.png') center center / cover no-repeat;
  }
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1200px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .navbar {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
.navigation-main {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navigation-main {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
.navigation-main li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.navigation-main li a {
  color: DodgerBlue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lobster";
}
ul.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navigation-main ul {
  display: block;
}
.navigation-main a.active {
  color: lightgreen;
  font-family: "Lobster";
  font-size: 30px;
}
.main_nav {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.navigation-main a.donate {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  background-color: #9ea517;
  padding: 20px 18px!important;
  color: #fff!important;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  font-family: 'Aclonica';
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 1px!important;
}
.hvr-grow-rotate {
  background-color: #9ea517;
}
img {
  height: 80px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  img {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* NAVIGATION END!! */

/* Middle Section */

.main_mid {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .main_mid {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
}
.inner_mid {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .inner_mid {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .inner_mid {
    margin-top: 0 auto;
  }
}
.help_text {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
}
@media all and (max-device-width: 1200px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .help_text {
    line-height: 300px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
#button {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1200px) {
  #button {
    padding-bottom: 35px;
  }
}
.button:hover {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
.button {
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px 18px!important;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  font-family: 'Aclonica';
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 1px!important;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    font-family: 'Aclonica';
  }
}
a.button {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: red;
}
a.button:hover {
  color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>BEMC | Home</title>

<head>
  <!-- Links -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.0/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="B_hover.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap Links -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.3.5/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.3.5/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- Random -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Flowtype.js/1.1.0/flowtype.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Flowtype.js/1.1.0/flowtype.min.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hover.css/2.0.2/css/hover-min.css">
  <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.3.4/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Fonts -->

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker|Fontdiner+Swanky|Slackey' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Black+Ops+One|Luckiest+Guy" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>


<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/GalleryPlugins/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    // note that this doens't call hide   
    $('.inner_mid').delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');

    $('#button').delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');

    $('.help_text').delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="https://i.gyazo.com/fbb65627e5fe8a07b7d4b9d41db47e34.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
      <source src="Timelapse_star_sky_FULLHD_Free_background_video_ef.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="Timelapse_star_sky_FULLHD_Free_background_video_ef.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="Timelapse_star_sky_FULLHD_Free_background_video_ef.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="navigation-main nav navbar-right">
          <li class="B_underline_left "><a href="# hvr-underline-from-center">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="Gallery.php">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="History.php">History</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="donate hvr-grow-rotate hvr-shutter-out-vertical hvr-buzz hvr-pulse" href="">Donate</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p class="animated flash bounceOut main_mid">Gallery</p>
      <p class="animated shake flash inner_mid">Coming Soon...</p>
      <p class="help_text">Help us by donating!</p>
      <div id="button">
        <a href="#" class="button hvr-grow-rotate hvr-shutter-out-vertical hvr-buzz hvr-pulse" role="button">Donate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/GalleryPlugins/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

What am I missing any suggestions?
Here is my JSFIDDLE > http://jsfiddle.net/57PQm/71/

Comment: What div is concerned in this problem, what should it look like?

Comment: @CodeiSir It is the main divs with class of inner_mid main_mid and donate those overlap in mobile landscape view

Comment: First, putting the script before the doctype is not only invalid, it puts your page into "quirks mode". Put that where it belongs, either in the head or at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag. Your title element is also supposed to be in the head.

Comment: @Rob that wasnt me this websites code add section did that when i said to add jquery...

Comment: @KstreakOG Then you need to get that fixed. It's invalid and causes problems no matter who or what did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change all the `position: fixed;` to `position: relative;` for elements that can be resized when the screen size changes. `fixed` maintains the `<div>` tag's starting position and can grow and shrink from there. So, when you shrink to a mobile screen, the size of the text you have causes the `<div>` that contains them to resize and overlap the the next `<div>`. When you change the `position` to `relative`, the `<div>`'s are placed in order, and if something causes the `<div>` to be resized, then the `<div>`'s that follow it are adjusted and prevent overlapping.

You can see it fixed with the edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57PQm/78/

Comment: yes but in mobile if I wanted to make the divs have scroll wouldnt i have to change it to position absolute for scrolling to happen

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that since you're use bootstrap CSS: Separate your `div`'s with bootstrap elements. You'll get mobile friendly `div`'s that do not overlap in an instant. (Bootstrap can then work it's magic)

Then you can organize your `div`'s with those classes (Basic example):

```
<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        One
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        Two
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        Three
    </div>

</div>
```

Use this as a reference: 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/
Or this: 
https://bootstrapdocs.com
Or this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Comment: I dont understand what your getting at?

Comment: **"I am trying to make it so on mobile screen size when in landscape the other divs do not overlap. I cant get the div's to stay at certain space away from each other."**

I'm saying if you use the bootstrap css you can use the bootstrap elements to make your divs fit perfectly on the screen on all devices. Get bootstrap here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download and let me know if you need any additional help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting good results by changing the position of the elements `.main-mid`, `.inner-mid`, `.help-text` and `.button` from `fixed` to `relative`.

I think that would be a good avenue for you to explore.

I would also suggest tidying up your code and using bootstrap's grid system like [wolfsatyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5555667/wolfsatyr) mentioned.